# add break if only 2 rows on page

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add line break like `</div>` to end if only 2 rows on PAGE (not every 2 rows) (not in mysql).

My Code:

```
$results_per_page = 12;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active='1' ORDER BY vip DESC, date DESC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page);
$sth->execute();
while($answer=$sth->fetch()){ if (only 2 rows on PAGE) { blabla } }
```

Comment: SELECT just 2 records from database. There is no reason to select X and then write down just two of them.

Comment: @panther i need to select 12 rows, because i have 12 rows on home page. but i want to past after 2 rows html code (if only 2 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active='1' ORDER BY vip DESC, date DESC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page);
$sth->execute();

// better to get result in variable
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

if (count($result) == 2) {
   echo '</div>';
}

// to display rows
foreach($result as $row) {
    // $row is array, it contains your columns
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

Comment: thank you, but its not working. When on page 12 rows and i set if ($i == 2) it fires to. I need fire this code ONLY IF 2 ROWS on page

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer so, I didn't understand your need

Comment: thank you! Now it fires when it need, but now no rows on page (empty page) but your code is working fine. How i can display rows now?

Comment: I added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while($answer=$sth->fetch()){ 
    if ($i<2) {
       // do stuff...

    }
    else { echo '</div>';break; }
    $i++;
}
```

This code runs for **$i=0** and **$i=1** after it will echo  and exits from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
while($answer=$sth->fetch()){ 
   //do stuff
   $i++;
}
if($i==2){
echo "<div>Whatever You Wants.</div>";
}
```

It will **echo** if only 2 rows in the result.